# Scheduler in asp.net to fetch data from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduler

I have written a code to fetch news from a website.
The code includes UI page in which i am inserting name of website (from which data to be fetched) & on button click event it fetches the news.

The code is as follows :

```
<form runat="server" style="margin-left:10px;">
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSiteName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Get News"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/><br /><br /><br />
    <h3>Here are the latest news</h3><br />
    <div style="max-height: 350px; overflow: auto">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvRss" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" Width="90%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAddNews" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3 style="color: #3E7CFF"><%#Eval("Title") %></h3>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px">
                                    <%#Eval("PublishDate") %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <hr />
                                    <%#Eval("Description") %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <a href='<%#Eval("Link") %>' target="_blank">Read More...</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

The codebehind is as follows :

```
public class Feeds
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateRssFeed();
}

private void PopulateRssFeed()
{
    //string RssFeedUrl = "https://realty.economictimes.indiatimes.com/rss/topstories";
    string RssFeedUrl = txtSiteName.Text;
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("link").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         description = x.Element("description").Value
                     });
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    Description = i.description
                };

                feeds.Add(f);
            }
        }

        gvRss.DataSource = feeds;
        gvRss.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

what it does is it takes all the news from one particular website on button click event.

But i want to implement the same functionality using the scheduler! (want to eliminate button click event instead!)
Since i haven't worked on scheduler before, can anyone help me out or any suggestions as how to fetch the data (news) from multiple websites using scheduler & store it in database table instead of directly displaying them??

Answer (score 1):

At client side use  `setInterval(expression, timeout);`.

1) Create a WebMethod at you  webpage.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateNews()
{
    PopulateRssFeed();
}
```

2) Create a method at client side so that use Ajax to call that WebMethod.

```
var updateNews = function(){ $.ajax({ type: "POST", url:"YourWebpage.aspx/UpdateNews", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" });}
```

3) Use `SetInterval` and call your client side ajax method

```
setInterval(updateNews(), 5000);//every 5 second
```

Comment: so basically it will be like the buttonClick event will be fired automatically at the said time of interval?

Comment: i didn't get you, can you please explain it using my code?

Comment: you solution looks good, but If at any particular day the page is not opened then in that case will it load the data??

Comment: No.   For server side use https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx